# How to remove metamask wallet from second computer

Tags: metamask

I have two computers. On computer 1, I have metamask set up with a couple of accounts (second account created within MM, NOT imported) and I have several networks set up. Yes I have the seed phrase for my wallet.

I may need to reset my browser for a variety of reasons. Apparently this resets it to initial state and removes all extensions, including metamask.

I want to see if I can create/import this wallet on Computer 2, just to make absolutely sure it doesn't disappear. If this is successful, then I want to reset my browser on Computer 1, re-install/configure MM on computer 1, and then delete that copy of the wallet on computer 2.

How do I delete a wallet in MM on computer 2?

Comment: Your questions seems to say that removing the browser extension is not enough. Can you tell more about your setup? What browser, what os?